# Execute a script in my zshrc?

Tags: zshrc

S want to execute a script in zshrc and write the output in a variable

```
VAR=$( /path/to/tool/tool -parameter)
```

is this possible in zsh?

Comment: of curse but parameters won't work!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "parameters won't work". The code you posted above is fine in terms of syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, command substitution works in zsh just like other POSIX shells. See this section of the [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-substitution_002c-command).